# CodeIgniter 4: How do you enable user defined routes?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm just wondering how I can redirect to `StudProfile` after using the `UpStudProf` function. After running `UpStudProf` function, the URL became `http://localhost/csms/public/index.php/Home/StudProfile`, but it should be `http://localhost/Home/StudProfile` and is it possible to remove the Controllers name `Home` on the URL?

```
public function StudProfile(){

$crudModel = new Mod_Stud();
$data = [];
$data['user_data'] = $crudModel->orderBy('s_id', 'ASC')->findAll();
$data['title']      = 'SMS | STUDENT PROFILE';
$data['heading']    = 'Welcome to SMS';
$data['main_content']   = 'stud-prof';  // page name
return view('innerpages/template', $data);
}

public function UpStudProf(){
$crudModel = new Mod_Stud();
$s_id = $this->request->getPost('s_id');
$data = array(
    's_lrn'   => $this->request->getPost('s_lrn'),
    's_fname' => $this->request->getPost('s_fname'),
    's_mname' => $this->request->getPost('s_mname'),
    's_lname' => $this->request->getPost('s_lname'),
    );
$crudModel->upStud($data, $s_id);
return redirect()->to('Home/StudProfile'); //return to StudProfile
}
```

Routes.php

```
$routes->setDefaultNamespace('App\Controllers');
$routes->setDefaultController('Home');
$routes->setDefaultMethod('index');
$routes->setTranslateURIDashes(false);
$routes->set404Override();
$routes->setAutoRoute(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... is it possible to remove the Controllers name `Home` on the URL?

[Use Defined Routes Only](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/routing.html?highlight=redirect#use-defined-routes-only)

> When no defined route is found that matches the URI, the system will
> attempt to match that URI against the controllers and methods as
> described above. You can disable this automatic matching, and restrict
> routes to only those defined by you, by setting the `setAutoRoute()`
> option to `false`:

```php
$routes->setAutoRoute(false);
```

Secondly, after disabling automatic matching, declare your user-defined route:
**app/Config/Routes.php**

```php
$routes->get('student-profiles', 'Home::StudProfile');
```

Lastly: **\App\Controllers\Home::UpStudProf**,

[redirect(string $route)](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/general/common_functions.html?highlight=redirect#redirect)

> Parameters:    **$route** (string) – The reverse-routed or named route to
> redirect the user to.

Instead of:

```php
// ...
return redirect()->to('Home/StudProfile'); //return to StudProfile ❌
// ...
```

Use this:

```php
// ...
return redirect()->to('/student-profiles'); ✅
// ...
```

Comment: For the part `$routes->get('student-profiles', 'Home::StudProfile');`, I need to declare all of the pages, right?

Comment: @cjwrk *I need to declare all of the pages* Could you explain what you meant by that?

Comment: The other pages that I create. Mostly the menus. Since if  I change the `$routes->setAutoRoute(false);` it will not load the other pages, right?

Comment: @cjwrk That's absolutely correct. *You need to declare all of the pages*.

Comment: Okay noted with this! It tried it and it worked! Thank you so much :)